# Issue with a function to change window in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a function, within another py file (core.py) which runs a function called mainmenudirector() in (debugging.py) file. This function changes window and has worked for the past three window switches, ive copied the same code, done the same stuff and it does not "work". The mainmenu ui does come up but as another window, not a window switch. Any help would be appreciated. mainmenudirectorcore() is called within a function called loginchecker().

Ive tried this function mainmenudirectorcore() within the debugging.py file and it works perfectly just like my other similar window changing functions. Ive also used .close()
Works, but new ui (mainwindow) opens but in another window

````py
DEBUGGING.PY FILE
########################################
import core, sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
#load both ui file
uifile_1 = 'login_menu.ui'
form_1, base_1 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_1)

uifile_2 = 'register_menu.ui'
form_2, base_2 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_2)

uifile_3 = 'dialog_register_sucess.ui'
form_3, base_3 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_3)

uifile_4 = 'dialog_register_fail.ui'
form_4, base_4 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_4)

uifile_5 = 'dialog_login_fail.ui'
form_5, base_5 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_5)

uifile_6 = 'main_menu.ui'
form_6, base_6 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_6)


class loginwindow(base_1, form_1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_1,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        #login button
        self.button = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'pushButton')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.logindirect)
        #register button
        self.button=self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton,'pushButton_2')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.regdirect)
        #username field
        self.username = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'lineEdit')
        # password field
        self.password = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'lineEdit_2')
        #label for database ip
        self.databaseip=self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLabel, 'label_5')
        self.databaseip.setText("Database ip:"+core.dbhost)

        def mainmenudirector(self):#mainmenu director
           self.hide()
           self.main = mainmenuwindow()
           self.main.show()
           self.close()

class mainmenuwindow(base_6, form_6): #mainwindow
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_6,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = loginwindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
#######################################################################################
#CORE.PY FILE 
import debugging
import hashlib, uuid , os , mysql.connector
dbhost="localhost"
def mainmenudirectorcore():
    global mainmenudirectorcore
    from debugging import loginwindow
    mainmenudirectorcore = loginwindow()
    mainmenudirectorcore.mainmenudirector()

def loginchecker(username_verify_login, password_verify_login):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="pwdpwd",
        database="mydatabase"
    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    a1 = str(username_verify_login)
    a2 = str(password_verify_login)

    cursor = mydb.cursor()

    salt = "5gz"
    db_password = a2 + salt
    h = hashlib.md5(db_password.encode())
    print(h.hexdigest())

    sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s AND password = %s "
    val = (a1, h.hexdigest())
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    results = cursor.fetchall()

    print(results)

    if results:
        print("welcome"+a1+"!")
        mainmenudirectorcore()
    else:
        print("error")
        global logfail
        from debugging import loginwindow
        logfail = loginwindow()
        logfail.logfailfunc()


def registerchecker(rusername,rfirstname,rlastname,rpassword,rconfirmpassword):
    a1=str(rusername)
    a2=str(rfirstname)
    a3=str(rlastname)
    a4=str(rpassword)
    a5=str(rconfirmpassword)

    if a4 != a5 or a4=='' or a5=='':
        print("Passwords do not match or are empty")
        #reg fail dialog
        global regfail
        from debugging import regwindow
        regfail = regwindow()
        regfail.regfailfunc()
    else:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            passwd="pwdpwd",
            database="mydatabase"
        )


        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        sql2 = "SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username=%s"
        val = (a1)
        cursor.execute((sql2), (val,))
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        if not data:
            print("not found")
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()

            salt = "5gz"
            db_password = a4 + salt
            h = hashlib.md5(db_password.encode())
            print(h.hexdigest())
            sql = "INSERT INTO accounts(username, password,firstname,lastname) VALUES (%s, %s,%s,%s)"
            val = (a1, h.hexdigest(), a2, a3)
            mycursor.execute(sql, val)

            mydb.commit()

            print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
            #running registration confirmation
            # from debugging import regwindow
            global regconfirm
            from debugging import regwindow
            regconfirm = regwindow()
            regconfirm.regconfirmfunc()


        else:
            print("found, registration un sucessfull. ")
            # reg fail dialog
            from debugging import regwindow
            regfail = regwindow()
            regfail.regfailfunc()```
````

Comment: well first your not using the  `if __name__ == "__main__":` which ought to be there

Comment: you import core and sys but never use them in this code?

Comment: i do. ill send some more code

Comment: ```pythonif __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = loginwindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())```

Comment: this is just sections of the code where the issue may be present, just small snippets of it. rest of code are other functions, ive tried to # with detail on what files im using above.

Comment: also the self.setupUi() kind of needs to be seen as well

Comment: ```class loginwindow(base_1, form_1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_1,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        #login button
        self.button = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'pushButton')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.logindirect)```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9BFjZYiw

Comment: Okay can I ask why you are choosing to do it this way?  Is it because you cannot work directly with your UIs perhaps because they were created via the Designer?  Or is there some other reason for this extra complexity that you are implementing here?

Comment: @elco_benoz provide a [MRE]

Comment: @DennisJensen yes i am using the designer.

Comment: @eyllanesc https://pastebin.com/DrFqNTux

Comment: @elco_benoz I have not asked for a link, the MRE must be in your question, otherwise your question will be off-topic.

Comment: @eyllanesc sure i have changed the code in the question

Comment: sure ty @DennisJensen